# Recurcison Java weird behaviour, printing nodes

Tags: java, recursion, linked-list

Code:

```
public class NodeType {

    public int value;
    public NodeType next;

    public NodeType(){
        value = 0;
        next = null;
    }

    public void printFollowingNodesInOrder(){
        System.out.println(this.value);
        while(this.next != null){
            this.next.printFollowingNodesInOrder();
        }
    }
}
```

Test class:

```
public class TestClass {

    public static void main(String[] args){

        NodeType nodeOne = new NodeType();
        NodeType nodeTwo = new NodeType();
        NodeType nodeThree = new NodeType();

        nodeOne.value = 1;
        nodeTwo.value = 2;
        nodeThree.value = 3;

        nodeOne.next = nodeTwo;
        nodeTwo.next = nodeThree;

        nodeOne.printFollowingNodesInOrder();       
    }   
}
```

When I run this main method, the method does not seem to exit after 3.
The output is:
1
2
3
3
3
3
3
3
3

Can anyone see where the problem is?

Comment: You need to put exit condition for your recursion to stop.

Comment: To those who would upvote these kinds of questions, listen to Joel Spolsky's and Jeff Atwood's podcast (the people who created this site), they STRONGLY discourage questions of this type: "Here's my code, tell me what characters to change".  It pollutes the site.  But don't take my word for it.  Ask the founders of this site.

Comment: @EricLeschinski Hi Eric. Sorry for polluting the site. I have been working on this code for about half an hour and I have no one to ask around me. What should I do in such situation? ( No sarcasm. ) Thank you.

Comment: it just humane to help someone in need. There are many reasons why a person can make a mistake like this - call it silly, but some day you may work too hard and your brain just tires, and you could write rubbish you wouldn't believe you did, after you take a nap and get back to work.

Comment: The issue is that the question is "too localized".  Kind of like my question: "Why is there a red car outside my window now?".  Should I ask that kind of question?  Would this question benefit anyone other than me? The idea is to leave quality artifacts for the Google to crawl, so when someone types in a question into google, and your page comes up, they slap their forehead and think: "I don't have this person's exact problem" and get frustrated.  Make the question more generalized, instead of making this site an extension of how you program.  "Programming by brownian motion through SO" is bad

Comment: @EricLeschinski Can you please generalize this question, so I can edit it? ( Please keep in mind that you do not know the problem is with while() and if(), before asking the question and reading the answers. ) Thank you.

Comment: There is no general question in here.  It is a question of type: "Here's my code, tell me my syntax error".  The system is supposed to downvote you for doing that, but the problem is the people who answer are so addicted to getting upvotes that they encourage you.  I'm here to tell you that the founders of this site don't want you doing that.  Try to formulate the question in a way where at least 10 other people on the earth would also have this same problem.  Here is the talk page on this concept: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/60342/how-to-answer-do-my-work-for-me-questions

Comment: @EricLeschinski Then can you please answer my first question? What am I supposed to do? Give up? Or contact you personally? Find a poluted site and ask my question there? ( I am not even asking why you care so much about the founders of the site or google crawls, because that question is too localized. ) What makes you think that people here actually care about upvotes? Can you convert them to dollars? ( That is a generalized question. )

Comment: Token economies are very addictive, it's what makes world of warcraft the most addictive thing ever.  You are supposed to avoid asking localized questions.  The optimal solution is for you to receive down votes for asking localized spot my syntax error for me questions to discourage you from doing that.  But considering people scramble over each other for up votes on bad questions, the next best thing is get a moderator to flag and close the question as too localized.  But I think the only thing that will halt the tens of thousands of these types of questions is a site policy change.

Comment: @EricLeschinski I still do not see an answer to my question, what am I supposed to in my situation? Anyway, thanks. Please flag this question so it can be closed, and I will give you as many tokes as you want if there is a way. Have a good life. Thanks.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/20893/discussion-between-eric-leschinski-and-koray-tugay)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
while (this.next != null)
```

is looping forever once it starts calling `printFollowingNodesInOrder` on the final node, because the second to last node (the one where the function is being called) has a `next` that will never go away. You don't need to do it in a loop when you're using recursion to access the next node. Take the loop out and it will work, but be sure to check for null before calling the function.

Comment: Actually it loops forever on the second to last one. (for the last one the condition is false)

Comment: You're right. Didn't notice it was calling the function on .next, not as .next

Comment: If it loops forever on the second to last one, should it not print 22222?

Comment: @KorayTugay, no, because it is calling `printFollowingNodesInOrder` on its `next` pointer, which in the case of the second node is 3. Inside the call with the third node as the parameter, it exits after printing because the third node's `next` is null. It then returns to the calling function (printFollowingNodesInOrder with the second node) and the loop moves on to its next iteration, calling the function again with the third node as the parameter again.

Answer (score 5):

Change

```
while(this.next != null){
```

to

```
if(this.next != null){
```

You would need a loop if you were printing the list iteratively. In a recursive solution, you don't.

Answer (score 2):

You don't have a base case and also default exit condition for your recursive method.

Answer (score 1):

your print function should siimply go this way:

```
public void printFollowingNodesInOrder(){
    System.out.println(value);
    if(next != null){
        next.printFollowingNodesInOrder();
    }
}
```